# SQL Group by and count intersection of rows from same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Essentially I have a table:

name, value, user_id

Which is essentially a key,value pair along with the user_id who owns that row. What I want to do is know which users share similar key value pairs (counts only).

E.g. if user1 had:

```
name: "test", value: 1
name: "test2", value: 2
name: "test3", value: 3
name: "test4", value: 4
```

and if user2 had:

```
name: "test", value: 1
name: "test2", value: 3
name: "test4", value: 4
```

and if user3 had:

```
name: "test4", value: 4
name: "test2", value: 3
```

I'd expect to see:

Intersection:

```
         name,   value,  name,   value, count
Group 1: test,    1,     test4,   4,     3
Group 2: test4,   4,     test2,   3,     2
```

Obviously i've only listed 3 sets of users for examples but there could be N number of users with each having N number of sets of key value pairs

(assuming a minimum match quantity of 2).

Basically the intersection grouped by the user_id. I feel like I am missing something obvious here, but I do know that this query can lead to quite exponentional results as it will be matching all possible combinations, however, this doesn't have to be real time so I am happy to come up with ways to mitigate this in the future

EDIT: Just to be clear, there could be n number of users each with n number of sets of key-value pairs, not just the two users there.

Comment: I recommend you be polite and correct. I mean previous comment about my code that you have deleted.There's many variants in sql to write and you can't judge, because it's correct.

Comment: @OlgaRomantsova apologies! It wasn't meant to come off that way I didn't mean for it to be delete your code I meant I was trying to delete my code! Your code was 100% fine, I was just trying to make it clear to someone else reading that if they saw it they would be confused because I changed the above question! You are right - there are multiple correct ways in SQL and yours was 100% correct. Sorry again - that was my mistake definitely was not my intention to be rude! Just to clarify I was not judging your code at all - only the way I incorrectly asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using two users as an example, one method is:

```
select name, value, count(*)
from t
where user_id in (:user1, :user2)
group by name, value
having count(distinct user_id) = 2;
```

Or, if you don't have duplicates within a user:

```
select name, value
from t t1 join
     t t2
     using (name, value)
where t1.user_id = :user1 and t2.user_id = :user2;
```

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear enough in my original question - I've updated it but basically there is the possibility of N number of userIds and n number of key-value sets. So basically I'm not just looking for userId = `2` if that makes sense

Comment: @HarrisonLucas . . . I think it should be clear how to modify the first query for any number of users.

Comment: Sorry gordon - yep that is clear! I have made an absolute mess of this question so I apologies - I asked the wrong question initially but have now updated it. My mistake!